# .htm and .html files won't render in Safari or Chrome

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, safari, rendering

I'm on MacOS and working through the first HTML module on Codecademy and copy/pasted the code from a completed first project about Brown Bears into Word and TextEdit. TextEdit saves as .html and Word saves as .htm, but for some reason neither render the code in Safari or Chrome. What am I missing? I change the 'open with' setting to  either browser, and all I'm shown in the browser when I open either file (each containing the same raw text) is the raw text.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I can't seem to paste the html code in here to reference. I wonder why.

Answer (score 4):

I can see how that can be frustrating. The solution is to change the preferences in TextEdit.

1. Open TextEdit Preferences (Click on TextEdit at the top-left and select Preferences. Or use the keyboard shortcut CMD + ,)
2. In the **New Document** select **plain text** for the format
3. In the **Open and Save** check the option that starts **Display HTML files...**

Once you make these changes, you can copy your HTML code into a new TextEdit and save the file with a '.html' extension and successfully open it in your browser.

Best of luck in your learning! Hope that helps!

P.S. I recommend using a richer editor (I use VScode). Nothing wrong with TextEdit but a more capable editor will help a lot (ex. reduce errors, add colors for ease of understanding, etc.).

Comment: You. Are. Fantastic. Steps 1,2,3 worked perfectly and I just downloaded VScode which also kicks ass. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i'd recommend a better software (IDE) if you are pursuing to code in the future (especially in web development) as it will make your life much easier. I'd suggest sublime text or visual studio code.

In relation to your question, the .html file should technically work. Try double clicking the file and it should take you to the browser. If not, then drag the file onto the web browser and it should display it. Again if this does not work, then the issue lies inside your file type / file in general.

If the error continues to persist, then try and start of with something simple such as:

```html
<body>
<h1> Test </h1>
</body>
```

If this shows then, there might be some minor error in the code you were originally inputting before.

Hopefully this works.

Comment: Thanks Shean. I tried <body>
<h1> Test </h1>
</body> to no avail either. I wonder if it's something in my browser settings.

Comment: May I ask what you are presented with when clicking on the file.html? Does it open in the browser and present nothing or does it give a certain prompt with options?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have saved the file like helloWorld.html.txt . This usually happens if you use a text editor like notepad and unfortunately windows automatically hides the .txt part of the file and you still see it as .html file. Can you just right click on the file and goto properties. Then send us a screenshot. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you need apache or negnix , and move your file to specified folder.

1. try http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1
   You can see "It works!". If it doesn't,open CLI and type this cmd `sudo apachectl restart`, and then try again.
2. open the folder  `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. Edit the file `test.html` and save your code. then open http://localhost/test.html.

Now, You can see the html code will be render.

Answer (score 0):

Add Safari and Chrome to allow full disk access.

I just got them working.

Open:

```
System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access -> 

Scroll to bottom -> tap "+" icon -> 

Select Safari & Google Chrome -> tap "Open" button
```

It will restart the applications and ask for your password.

You should now see Safari & Google Chrome Toggles on with the blue on state.

See screenshot below.

[image]